# How to generate Model layer, Persistence layer and service layer from a single configuration file

Tags: spring, hibernate, ant, model, persistence

I am using hibernate to persist data on a MySql database.

Now I am already configuring what my business model is in the hibernate configuration file.
What I am looking for is, are there any tools that on building/deploying the application will generate the Model Layer (POJOs), Persistence Layer and the Service Layer (Business logic) for the controllers to communicate with the database server. In short I wish to generated all the basic essentials from a single configuration point.

Ant or Spring or combination of other frameworks, anything that can achieve the solution.

Any reference to an existence thread or a handful document would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your closest bet is [Grails](http://grails.org/).

I'm not a fan of what you'd like to do.  Code generation can result in a brittle system.

Comment: Thanks a lot duff.
I actually wish to have a single point of configuration resulting into layers of object Hierarchy.
So Hibernate is a good choice for DB connectivity, and Maven for building the app.

Comment: Not in my opinion.  I don't like Hibernate much, and I really detest Maven.

Answer (score 1):

spring roo can be also good option to look at as your stack is based on spring framework. 
Another option which can be used is MyEclipse IDE for Spring this supports code generation based on domain/table.

Comment: I was also going to suggest Roo.  I think the latest version(s) actually have a reverse-engineering feature.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys.
I will check out Spring roo.
@Jigar, I am not very comfortable relying on IDEs to do this.

Comment: Thanks Jiga bhai. I think I am in love with Spring-roo. It is absolutely amazing. Just one thing:
It does everything in the background. So I would still try once to use hbm2ddl and hbm2java personally to reverse-engineer the tables to pojo and then get back to roo.
But thanks a lot again for suggesting this.